# MarkLogic 8 Ingestion Job to Denormalize Collections in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, marklogic

I have 3 database views that come from a relational database and they get ingested into MarkLogic as 3 collections.

These 3 views are related to each other.

I want to join this data and then ingest it all into one denormalized collection.

I could create a new SQL view with the joins and then ingest that into a new collection.

Or I could take the existing collections in MarkLogic and setup a background job to create this new collection.

Two questions:

1) What is the recommended approach?

2) If I go the background approach how should I set this up? I want to use Javascript in this case, so would I use the client side or the server side API? Would I set this up to run automatically, on a schedule or manually?

Comment: With respect to the background approach, are you talking about a one-time data load, or something on-going?

Comment: This would be ongoing. If the view changes (inserts or updates) then I have to have a strategy to update MarkLogic to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tutan, take a look at [Corb2](https://github.com/marklogic/corb2). That's a tool for processing bunches of content -- you specify one module that lists the URIs that need work and a second module that specifies what should be done to one individual module. As of very recently, Corb2 supports the use of Server-side JavaScript to write these modules.